# Handling exceptions in a class library of a plug-in architecture

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm developing a plug-in architecture to allow the execution of heterogeneous tasks through the use of appropriate plug-in, which would be loaded from one or more libraries (DLL files from a specified directory).

First I worked on defining the interface that must be implemented by each plug-in, so I created the following C# interface.

```
public interface ITaskProcessor
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Version { get; }
    string Author { get; }
    string Description { get; }

    void Execute(Stream sourceStream, Stream destStream);
}
```

In essence, in defining this interface, I'm assuming that the data relating to a task must be previously stored in a file and that the results will be stored in another file. For this reason, the `Execute` method requires two `Stream` objects as parameters.

The opening and closing of both streams are operations common to all plug-ins, so I decided to perform them in the class `TaskProcessorContext`, as follows.

```
public class TaskProcessorContext
{
    private ITaskProcessor m_TaskProcessor;

    public TaskProcessorContext(ITaskProcessor executor)
    {
        m_TaskProcessor = executor;
    }

    public void Execute(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
    {
        InternalExecute(sourceFileName, destFileName);
    }

    private void InternalExecute(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
    {
        FileStream sourceStream = null;
        FileStream destStream = null;

        try
        {
            sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFileName);
            destStream = new FileStream(destFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            m_TaskProcessor.Execute(sourceStream, destStream);   // invoking the method of a plug-in
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(e.ParamName, e.Message);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(e.Message, e.ParamName, e);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(e.Message, e.FileName, e);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(e.Message, e);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException e)
        {
            throw new PathTooLongException(e.Message, e);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(e.Message, e);
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException e)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(e.Message, e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new IOException(e.Message, e);
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException e)
        {
            throw new System.Security.SecurityException(e.Message, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sourceStream != null)
            {
                sourceStream.Close();
                sourceStream.Dispose();
                sourceStream = null;
            }

            if (destStream != null)
            {
                destStream.Close();
                destStream.Dispose();
                destStream = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it appropriate to catch and re-throw all exceptions that may occur during the opening of the stream, passing the raised exception as inner exception in order to avoid losing the stack trace.

If the two streams are opened correctly, ie if no exceptions occur when opening the stream, then the `Execute` method of a certain plug-in is invoked.

Clearly, you can not know in advance the processing operations performed by each plug-in, so it's not even possible to know in advance the exceptions that might occur during such processing. However, I need a way to know any errors that occur during the execution of the `Execute` method of a plug-in: in other words, I would like that the `Execute` method of each plug-in may throw additional exceptions, but the `TaskProcessorContext.Execute` method should catch it and re-throw it without losing the stack trace...

It seems to me that the only way to manage this is to define a class to use for exceptions thrown by the plug-ins. For example, I could create the class `TaskProcessingException`, so any exceptions that occur within the `Execute` method of a specific plug-in should be re-thrown using this new class, as in the following example:

```
public class PluginExample : ITaskProcessor
{
    // ...

    public void Execute(Stream sourceStream, Stream destStream)
    {
        try
        {
            // ...
        }
        catch (SomeSpecificException e)
        {
            throw new TaskProcessingException(e.Message, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

As a consequence, I should also add the following code to the `Execute` method of the `TaskProcessorContext` class, in order to catch `TaskProcessingException` from the plug-ins:

```
catch(TaskProcessingException e)
{
    throw new TaskProcessingException(e.Message, e);
}
```

In this way, users of the `TaskProcessorContext` class would have the ability to catch and manage all exceptions that may occur during the call to its `Execute` method.

Is the above approach correct?
Are there alternative approaches?

**UPDATE**

I modified the `TaskProcessorContext.Execute` method, so that exceptions thrown by specific implementations of `ITaskProcessor` interface are relaunched within a custom TaskProcessingException, so that the caller can know where the exception occurred and handle it properly.

```
public void Execute(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{
    FileStream sourceStream = null;
    FileStream targetStream = null;

    try
    {
        sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFileName);
        targetStream = new FileStream(destFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        try
        {
            m_TaskProcessor.Execute(sourceStream, targetStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Catch and re-throw the exceptions
            // launched from a specific plug-in.
            throw new TaskProcessingException(e.Message, e);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sourceStream != null)
        {
            sourceStream.Close();
            sourceStream.Dispose();
            sourceStream = null;
        }

        if (targetStream != null)
        {
            targetStream.Close();
            targetStream.Dispose();
            targetStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you catching all these exceptions and simply re-throwing them with the inner exception? What use do you have of that? it simply wraps the exception with another one.

Comment: Do you want plugins to throw error info to consumer? If yes, then your approch looks ok at initial observation but if you do not want that then you need to associate logger such as log4net to this which will log the error info. Also, for your context object it should also have error property i guess, so that consumer will check if any error before processing for output.

Comment: @Amit: Yes, I want plugins to throw error info to consumer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Could I simply write `catch { throw; }`?

Comment: How about no catch at all? :) If you only throw, there's no point in catching

Comment: As a guideline, i would advise all plugin writers to throw some sort of conformed exception which should explain to the end-user what happened. I see no point in your plug-in manager to be caching any of these exceptions if you don't do anything with them. If you want to log, you could simply `catch (Exception e)` and then `throw` again after logging.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: But consumers should know that, for example, the `FileNotFoundException` could be launched during the opening of the stream by invoking the `Execute` method...

Comment: Then put it in your API's documentation.

Comment: You can also avoid all the catch statements and still enjoy the benefits of the finally block if you `using` your streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you are putting too much pressure on the plugin developers by requiring them to throw only exceptions of a certain type.

Since there is no way of inforcing this behavior, i.e. throw only `TaskProcessingException` from within the pugin execution context neither you nor the consumers of your class should rely on it.

On the other hand, you could introduce the `TaskProcessingException` as a way for the plugin to signal a failed expectation when executing a task such as bad data received from a stream. In such cases this would be treated as a business exception and the consumer of your `TaskExecutionContext` would be able to differenciate it from other exception types thrown from from the `TaskExecutionContext`.

Comment: Actually there is no way to force the classes that implement the `ITaskProcessor` interface to throw exceptions using a specific type of exception...